# change constant angular content with grunt task

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I have some constant in angular that set my remote according in my enviromment:

like

```
app.constant('fooConst', {
  urlBase: window.location.origin + '/bar/',
  urlBaseWebservice: window.location.origin + '/foo/' + 'bar/rc/'
  // urlBase: 'http://localhost:8080/mvsaudeweb/',
  // urlBaseWebservice: 'http://localhost:8080/foo/' + 'bar/rc/'
});
```

what i con do for make the grunt task 'dist' change automatically to window.location.origin?

EDIT:

i solve this using grunt-replace 
i dont need of window.location.origin, the replacement is empty string for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used this https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant to build apps with different configuration sets.